# Does Syncthing transmit filenames in plaintext?

Tags: syncthing

I regularly use Syncthing to sync files and I love it. I also use pass to manage my passwords and while the file contents are encrypted on my system, the file names are not.

Since the file names are named after my usernames I need to know these are kept secret as well. I know files are encrypted when being sent via Syncthing, but what about the filenames? Could someone intercept those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read about the protocol specifications of Syncthing [here](https://docs.syncthing.net/specs/index.html). The [Block Exchange Protocol specification](https://docs.syncthing.net/specs/bep-v1.html#bep-v1) will directly answer your question: It uses Transport Layer Security (TLS), so nothing is transmitted unencrypted. The device IDs you see are, in fact, certificate thumbprints, so you are directly trusting another device’s unique encryption certificate. Since mutual trust must be established, the security baseline is very high.

TLS is not susceptible to man-in-the-middle attacks. While the certificate could perhaps be retrieved, it is public information (just like with HTTPS). The private key is just that: Private. It is never sent over the network.

---

There’s even a specification in the works that would allow syncing to untrusted devices. They would not see contents or filenames.

Comment: Excellent that gives me great confidence to use it like Franks Redhot